# Write dynamic content inside dynamic div

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating dynamic `<div>` blocks with `id`s that contain `i` from for loop.

I am getting error if I want to get a specific `<div>` in dynamic `<div>`s

Error: `Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined.`

```
document.getElementById("roomModal_"+i).document.getElementById("modalDialog_"+i).document.getElementById("modalContent_"+i).document.getElementById("modalBody_"+i).document.getElementById("images");
```

If I just write `document.getElementById("images")` then I can get it, but the point is that each dynamic `<div>` block has its own content.

https://jsfiddle.net/oryz8eLs/

Am I missing something?

Comment: "the point is that each dynamic `<div>` block has its own content" — An ID must be unique in a document. Write valid HTML, then you won't have that problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oryz8eLs/3/

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for your suggestion. It made me to take a look at my ids again. I found one duplicated id. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getElementById()` will return an object and you can't call `.document.getElementById` on object.

So you can't nest the js selectors as you do now, instead use `querySelector` like :

```
var img = document.querySelector("#roomModal_"+i+" #odalDialog_"+i+" #odalContent_"+i+" #odalBody_"+i+" #images");
```

Since you're using `id`'s and the `id` should be unique in same document you could just do :

```
var img = document.querySelector("#images");
//Or
var img = document.getElementById("#images");
```

To get the element with specific `images`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `querySelector()` worked perfectly. Thanks for your suggestion.